# List is not picking up the mail from Drop folder

Tags: list, email, discussion-board

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [incoming mail just sits in the drop folder](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13253/incoming-mail-just-sits-in-the-drop-folder)

I have followed all the steps as mentioned in this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/Video/ff679958to to enable Team Discussion list to receive email. But problem is that when I send mail it reach to the Drop folder but the the list does not pick up the mail from the Drop folder it remains there.

Can anyone help how to solve it?