# Sharepoint 2013 SP1 incoming email in load balanced farm not working on both servers

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have 2 SharePoint 2013 WFE servers with a Cisco CSS VIP load balancer.
I have applied service pack 1 and may 2014 CU.

I have configured the basic scenario incoming email on both servers as per this article [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc262947(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc262947%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

My MX records are pointing to the CSS VIP (the Cisco load balancer). Emails are delivered successfully to a the Cisco load balancer which routes the emails to the one of the two servers. The only problem is that sharepoint picks up the emails from one server only and not both. If I run the "Timer Service recycle" job and kill the first server, sharepoint starts picking up emails from the other server.

What could go wrong?  is there any additional configuration needed so that sharepoint check both servers?

Comment: check this blog to configure the incoming email in load balancer farm...you need to focus on step 4...http://sharepointlive.wordpress.com/2011/06/07/sharepoint_incoming_email/

Comment: That's what I did, except I have SharePoint 2013 and not 2010 nor 2007.

Comment: is same email delivered to both servers? what i am thinking some load balancer logic causing the issue

Comment: no. email is being delivered to only one server at a time. SharePoint picks up the email from node A  only and never from node B until I restart "Timer service recycle" job and the email pick up is switched.

Comment: any host header entry in the WFE?

Comment: where exactly you want me to check this?

Comment: on the server, check the host file(C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc)  may be something forced over their.

Comment: Oh the hosts files. Actually, there was an entry on one of the servers that is working (127.0.0.1   domainname). I removed it and restarted smtp service and have not noticed any changes. still does not work on the second server.

Comment: just a quick question, if I copy the eml file from the drop folder on wfe1 to the drop folder on wfe2, sharepoint should pick up both eml files?

Comment: i am not sure, i never did, you can try.

Comment: also check the timer jobs on central admin, see if any job for 2nd wfe disabled or failed

Comment: I am not sure if this is a bug or limitation in sharepoint 2013?

Comment: I would recommend to open a case with MSFT support to get final words. They tool to diagnose it.

Comment: I think I will have to. thanks for your support/help.

Comment: Have you found a resolution to your issue? I'm running into this issue too time to time. Below thread being very helpful in my case. I started thinking whether or not you can use "basic Scenario" in a multi server farm? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13253/incoming-mail-just-sits-in-the-drop-folder/154172#154172